# Compiling in g++ for gprof

Tags: profiling, g++, compilation, gprof

I do not understand the documentation for gprof regarding how to compile your program for profiling with gprof. In g++, is it required to compile with the `-g` option (debugging information) in a addition to the `-pg` option or not. In each case I get different results, and I would like to see where the bottlenecks in my application are in release mode, not in debug mode, where many optimizations are left out by the compiler (e.g. inlining)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343

Comment: `-g` does not mean that optimizations are turned off.  `-O` controls opimization.  You can compile with both `-g` and `-O2` for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/binutils/gprof_2.html) shows that you can do either, noting that you need -g for [line by line profiling](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/binutils/gprof_17.html).  So if you want to profile under release conditions, and can accept not doing line-by-line, you should be able to compile without -g.

Comment: I am only interested in function calls, not line by line profiling. Without the -g option, many functions that are being called do not show up. I do not think this is due to inlining, because many of those methods are big ones (50+ lines of code).

Comment: @myahya, I think it very well may be inlining.  By default, GCC may inline functions up to 400 internal GCC instructions long (I know these don't map directly to lines of code); see http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/gcc/trunk/annotate/99780/gcc/params.def#L58.  Also, what compilation flags are you using?